# The Health proposal is in commitment phase

Tags: discussion

Since I saw a few questions closed for being too health-oriented, I thought some might be interested in the  [Health proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66048/health?referrer=3bnJk5Umd0S9V8Fef65Ucg2), which is now in commitment phase.

Comment: I think the big fear with cycling is where a guy asks a question about their own health, some bright spark answers "You'll be OK", the guy goes out for a ride and drops dead halfway. Quite rightly you have to be very careful with medical advice. I'd be interested to know how you cater for that scenario.

Comment: Indeed. I'm not going to commit to that SE since I dont think SE can do that topic safely, but I hope more people commit so that questions can be migrated there.

Comment: @PeteH With a disclaimer to drop any liability (not sure if that's even necessary, I guess people will look into it once the SE gets launched).

Comment: @Batman I don't think that the advice of a physician during an appointment is necessarily always safer than a community's advice with hopefully referenced claims.  At least that should provide an interesting complement. But yeah either way that should be a good place to dump the decently good health questions posted here :)

Comment: I can't wait for SE Legal!

Comment: @PeteH Yes same here!  There is a [Law proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/67858/law?referrer=VbiBXJnq7T0Ioi5i8nXuKg2), I guess it will enter in commitment phase soon.